# How to use Selenium with the Wappalyzer browser plugin

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I want to make a python CLI for Wappalyzer (https://www.wappalyzer.com), but it is a browser plugin. The plugin identifies programs/frameworks running on a webpage, and I want to be able to use/get that information from a python script.  While they do have a paid API, I was wondering if it is possible to use Selenium and the ChromeDriver to visit the page with a chrome extension, and then retrieve the data generated by Wappalyzer.

Comment: have a look at [this](https://github.com/zhyc9de/WappalyzerApi) project.